# Поиск линии пикселей одного цвета C++

Tags: c++, qt, изображения

Есть изображения(ровная прямая линия может быть в любой стороны):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо вычислить с какой стороны находиться эта прямая(условно) линия и повернуть изображение, чтобы она была ВНИЗУ. 
Пробовал искать наибольшую длину, когда пиксели идут друг за другом, но получается очень медленно, так как 4 цикла на каждую нужно.

```
            for (int X = 0; X < image.height()/2; X++) {
            for (int Y = 0; Y < image.width(); Y++) {
                if (QColor(image.pixel(X,Y)).name()=="#ffffff")
                {
                    int i = Y+1;
                    int max_buffer;
                    while(QColor(image.pixel(X,i)).name()=="#ffffff")
                    {
                        max_buffer++;
                        i++;
                    }

                    if(max_buffer>max_top)
                    {
                        max_top = max_buffer;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Это цикл только для вверха, еще 3 для других сторон и затем сравнивать что больше и т.д.
Читал, что можно методом квадратов это реализовать и сделать более оптимизировано.
UPADETE:Изображение уже является бинарным(черно-белым, монохромным)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если срез всегда параллелен осям координат, то сканирующей линией с каждого направления посчитать количество белых пикселов в линии. Для среза это число по мере движения линии вырастет резко, ступенькой, для круглой стороны будет кривая - лежачая парабола - квадратный корень. Метод неустойчив даже к небольшому наклону.

Если направление среза произвольно, можно посчитать для изображения
 [моменты Ху](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment#Examples_2) и оценить ориентацию. Иx вычисление есть, например, в OpenCV.

Что-то я о простейшем применении моментов не подумал - вычислить центр масс фрагмента, содержащего усеченный круг, и найти, в каком направлении белые пикселы кончаются ближе от этого центра. Это будет перпендикуляр к искомому срезу.

```
 ll sumx = 0;
 ll sumy = 0;
 ll sumv = 0;
 for (int y = 0; y < image.height(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < image.width(); x++) {
            sumx += value[y][x] * x;
            sumy += value[y][x] * y;
            sumv += value[y][x];
        }
 }
 masscenterx = sumx / sumv;
 masscentery = sumy / sumv;
```

Comment: Идея с цетром масс логичная. Можете в кратце описать как найти его?

Comment: Так по определению - сложить все `value[i][j] * i` и `value[i][j] * j` и разделить на сумму `value[i][j]` - получатся координаты.

Comment: Но так мы получим центр самой картинку, а не усеченного круга, а он может быть смещен

Comment: Нет, белые пикселы за счет большего значения "притягивают" к себе центр

Comment: Можно цикл пожалуйста, до конца не могу понять как будет находиться именно центр масс фигуры

Comment: добавил псевдокод

Comment: Цвет пикслея берем в каяестве value, в данное случае либо 1 либо 0

Comment: Да, всё верно, 1 для белого

Comment: Ваш код работает идеально. Теперь запустить цикл в 4 стороны и сравнить расстояние?)

Comment: Да. Если есть помехи - можно попробовать пустить не одинарную, а тройную линию

Comment: Я дополню ваш ответ, хорошо?

Comment: Дополняйте, потом посмотрим

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял, прямая линия на изображении может быть параллельна одной из сторон изображения. В этом случае предлагаю следующий алгоритм поиска:

1. Встаем на край изображения в середину грани (будет 4 случая - x=0, y=h/2; x=w, y=h/2; x=w/2, y=0; x=w/2, y=h, где w и h соответственно ширина и высота изображения), далее для простоты разбираем для первого случая
2. Движемся в центр изображения (в рассматриваемом случае в сторону увеличения x) и ищем белый пиксель
3. Когда белый пиксель найден, проходим от 0 до высоты картинки по найденной x белого пикселя и считаем количество белых пикселей на этой линии, запоминаем.

Повторяем аналогично для четырех граней, искомая плоская грань соответствует той, где найденное количество белых пикселей максимальной.

Изображение для наглядности алгоритма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавлю, что у вас очень большой оверхед на сравнение цвета, сначала конвертация в `QColor`, потом конвертация в `QString` и потом сравнение строк. 
Я бы навскидку написал что-нибудь типа

```
QRgb pixel = image.pixel(X, Y);
if (qRed(pixel) == 255 && qGreen(pixel) == 255 && qBlue(pixel) == 255)
    ...
```

З.Ы. Немного подумал, по идее алгоритм устойчив к небольшому повороту изображения, но надо потестировать

З.Ы.Ы. Есть второй вариант алгоритма, можно посчитать набор расстояний от края картинки до первого встреченного белого пикселя, на какой грани разница между этими расстояниями будет минимальна, та грань является искомой. Какой из двух вариантов оптимальнее, предположить не могу, надо тестировать.

Comment: К сожалению, хоть это и полезный совет, но он не является ответом на поставленный вопрос. Пожалуйста, или перенесите его в комментарии, или добавьте в другой ответ, или перефразируйте ответ, чтобы он был ответом.

Comment: @Kromster пришлось быстро придумать быстрый и вроде точный алгоритм